# Generic method for creating a default fetch request

Tags: swift, core-data

I find it quite tedious to duplicate the query type every time. For example:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Animal> = Animal.fetchRequest()
```

Is it possible to create a generic method that will return the default request? Something like this:

```
let request = Animal.defaultFetchRequest() // request is NSFetchRequest<Animal>
```

I tried to write this:

```
protocol DefaultFetchable {
   associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
   
   static func defaultFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>
}

extension DefaultFetchable where Self: NSManagedObject {
   static func defaultFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<FetchableType> {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<FetchableType> = FetchableType.fetchRequest()
      return request
   }
}
```

But I get a build error: `Cannot assign value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to type 'NSFetchRequest<Self.FetchableType>'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be after something more like this so it generates the entity name from the class which is what is used to create the fetch request.

```
protocol DefaultFetchable {
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    
    static var entityName: String { get }
    static func defaultFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>
}

extension DefaultFetchable where Self: NSManagedObject, FetchableType == Self {
    
    static var entityName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
    
    static func defaultFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<FetchableType> {
        return NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
    }
    
}
```

Then your `Animal` class providing it's an `NSManagedObject` that conforms to `DefaultFetchable` should be able to create fetch requests like so:

```
let fetchRequest = Animal.defaultFetchRequest()
```